# Integrate twitter into iOS 5 but maintain backwards compatibility with older iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

Been following this great [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5519/beginning-twitter-in-ios-5)  on how to integrate twitter into your app. I know there are other ways that programmers have used to integrate twitter before iOS 5 but my question is this:

My app supports iOS 3.0+ so if I integrate twitter using just the iOS 5 way of doing it, how will this affect my users that aren't using iOS 5? Will it even work for them?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The official API framework wouldn't work unfortunately as the twitter app/integration is only available in iOS 5

A good solution is to use [ShareKit](http://getsharekit.com/),  a free API that allows you to integrate twitter, facebook and other social network support.

Comment: share kit is a horrible cumbersome mess of a thousand things you don't need or even want...

Comment: Thanks for the reply Rohan. Just wondering if I should then do it the way its been done before iOS 5 so then it would work for all versions of iOS?

Comment: Yes it would.... But depends on the current compatibility and how convenient and good that way is... Your choice... I believe ShareKit is good because you can also do so much more! Like facebook

Comment: :) sure thing didn't mean to rant... it's very late where I am :)

Comment: @Daniel out of curiosity Daniel, before I begin all this... What is in your opinion wrong with share kit. Thanks

Comment: I just don't like to bring along unnecessary baggage, I believe Share kit has most social networks which include many many unnecessary files, it also comes with it's own UI which in the past I had trouble detaching from the actual logic which I was after, I just have a very bad experience with loosing lots of time and in the end it was just too much of a "try to do everything -  but do nothing good". Facebook have a great iOS SDK, Twitter not so much but there are neat solutions, and who cares about Delicious, Google Reader, Pinboard, Instapaper, Read It Later - Do people even use these!

Comment: it's all about Facebook and Twitter for sharing, of course not mentioning Email but that's a given on iOS. All the apps I've done I've needed FB and/or Twitter, nothing else, plus I've always had my own look and feel about how I want the user to initiate a share, ShareKit isn't so friendly for that kind of thing...

Comment: You can detect if Twitter framework is available and if it is use it, else just use whatever you've been used to until now - in my case it's MGTwitterEngine.

Answer (score 5):

If you are OK by only making Twitter available for iOS 5 users, you can check if Twitter is available with this:

```
// Don't forget to import Twitter!
#import <Twitter/Twitter.h>
....
if([TWTweetComposeViewController class] != nil) {
    // your code here
}
```

Also, make sure that when adding the Twitter framework you set it as optional.

Answer (score 2):

You should look into [DETweetComposeViewController](https://github.com/doubleencore/DETweetComposeViewController). We built it just for this purpose. It is an iOS4 compatible re-implementation of the TWTweetComposeViewController.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I've come across that one before, and a discussion lead me to believe it's most unlikely to please Apple. I wouldn't recommend your solution for that reason. Anyway we should be making people on iOS 4 wish they had iOS 5, not break our backs giving them one less reason to update... If they're on iOS 4 then they should have an ugly Twitter experience.

Comment: I would love to know why you think Apple would not be pleased with this. We have had multiple high profile apps using this to great success.

Comment: I don't know, maybe this could have slipped through the loop, Apple are very stubborn when it comes to replicating their own design and features (remember the Photos.app pinch for iPad when it launched - that developer got his app banned for copying it - actually did a good job).

Answer (score 0):

Use weak linking and some code like the following:

```
 - (void)tweet
{
Class tweeterClass = NSClassFromString(@"TWTweetComposeViewController");

if(tweeterClass != nil) {   
    if([TWTweetComposeViewController canSendTweet]) {
        TWTweetComposeViewController *tweetViewController = [[TWTweetComposeViewController alloc] init];
        tweetViewController.completionHandler = ^(TWTweetComposeViewControllerResult result) {
            if(result == TWTweetComposeViewControllerResultDone) {

            }
            [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
        };

        [self presentViewController:tweetViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
    } else {
#if !(TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR)
        [self displayAlert:@"You can't send a tweet right now, make sure your device has an internet connection and you have at least one Twitter account setup."];
#else
        NSString *tweetString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://mobile.twitter.com/home?status=%@%@", [self urlEncode:@"Check out this awesome pic: "] ,[self urlEncode:[_blobTweet.shortUrl absoluteString]]];
        NSURL *tweetURL = [NSURL URLWithString:tweetString];
        if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:tweetURL]) { 
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:tweetURL]; 
        }
#endif
    }
} else {        
    // no Twitter integration could default to third-party Twitter framework

}
}

@end
```